# reporting bugs that don't affect all websites **yet**

Tags: support, bug-reports

I just posted a [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296009/new-badge-selected-new-goal-now-previous-new-badge-is-shown-in-activity-page) about an inconsistency in  the "BADGES" box of that I noticed on meta.stackoverflow.com (reverting to the previous "Newest" badge, after congratulating me on acquiring a new one in that box).

I posted the bug on meta.stackoverflow.com. I do assume that this affects other sites as well (but I have not noticed that far). But it cannot affect all sites, as not all sites have the new profile/acitvity layout (e.g. programmers.stackexchange.com doesn't).

According to the [help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) bu. gs for **all** sites are welcome here on meta.stackexchange.com.

Not being sure that this affects other sites (I don't get a badges that often) and being sure if it does it does not affect all sites *yet*, should I have posted that bug on this site instead anyway?

Comment: Ironically, there is a dup on MSO: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).

Comment: @psubsee2003 And of course I only searched on [metase] to see if that was already asked %-)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**, post it on which ever meta you want.

Stack Exchange has pretty much stated this in the blog post announcing the [MSO/MSE split](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), and they reinforced it in the Meta.SO post [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

And never feel like you must post it on Meta.SE.  To quote [Tim's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) blog post:

> When in doubt, you can always post your question on your local meta. If it’s clearly relevant to the engine or network as a whole, we’ll move it.

**The slightly longer answer** is there is some thought that should go into it, at least the way I see it. There are 2 questions you should ask yourself before posting

1. Who needs to know about this bug?  Is it my local community?  Or the wider community?  (and don't worry about Stack Exchange employees - they will see it which ever meta you post it in).
2. Is this a bug in the engine, the UI, or the design?  Since the design is (mostly) unique to the local site, it might be *more* applicable on your local child meta and probably best asked there.  If it is the engine or UI, then it could be applicable to everyone so it would be acceptable to post it on MSE, but it is still on-topic for your local meta.

The only general exceptions are posts about either apps ([ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) or [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)) or Careers.SO.  The developers who manage those projects have been requested to be posted to MSE... but still doesn't stop you from posting to your child meta if you want.  It is just more likely to get moved to MSE.