# HTML Entities on the button in Create Tag Synonym dialog

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, html-entities

The page: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

When I open the Create Tag Synonym dialog first, it looks fine

[image]

But if I check/uncheck the Merge Tags option, the button will look like this:

**Checked**

[image]

**Unchecked**

[image]

Traducir lines:

- Preview changes (Предпросмотр изменений) https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13015
- Create synonym (Создать синоним) https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12451

Comment: Related (I know you're the author of both posts): [Translated success popup-message for synonym deletion shows as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389079/348196)

Comment: Same page, same site. There is bug causing all translations to be double encoded, really no need to report each and every button, element, or link in its own bug report. It's lots of noise. Once the bug is fixed (6-8 weeks/months/years or never) all of those will be fixed as well. Hence it's a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard IIRC, SE staff explicitly told us that for their system each toast message must be separately handled with respect to showing HTML entities. They said that they had already gone through and changed all the ones which they found, and it was explicitly asked that separate reports be made for each remaining one which was found. So, these should be separate bug reports, until we're told differently by SE staff.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard sorry for creating of this kind of reports on MSE but we have no Russian-speaking CM staff on ru.so at the moment, no reason to create it on the meta.ru.so.

Comment: @aepot the real reason to post it here since it affects other Non-English sites.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Bugs, *of any type*, are explicitly permitted by SE to be reported on *any meta site*, even if the bug doesn't affect the site on which the bug is reported. Yes, it's nice to let other affected sites know about the issue, but the important thing is to let SE know about the bug, which currently doesn't happen unless a [tag:status-review] tag is added.

Comment: @Makyen related to the question of validity of reporting anywhere (with the general consensus that it's, indeed, fine): [How does one report a bug in Stack Overflow HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111070), [Does Stack Overflow fix bugs or problems reported on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212170), [reporting bugs that don't affect all websites yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257856), [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152)

Comment: Another one: [How to report a bug in a community which I don't want to join?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333501)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Oleg found the definitive one which I was remembering: "[Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/3773011)". Tim Post was an SE employee at the time that question was posted. (Thanks Oleg).

Comment: The mysterious [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) (*[numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)* in this case?).